# MySQL Wrong ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

```
SELECT `player`.`cid`, `player`.`k`, `player`.`d`, `gg`.`gg_id`, `gg`.`name`, `gg`.`img`, `cc`.`cid`, `cc`.`name`, `cc`.`class`, `cc`.`gg_id`
FROM `player` 
LEFT JOIN `cc` ON `cc`.`cid` = `player`.`cid` 
LEFT JOIN `gg` ON `gg`.`gg_id` = `cc`.`gg_id` 
ORDER BY (`k`-`d`) DESC
```

i want to order by the K minus the D values, but im not getting it correctly
what im a doing wrong? with or without DESC/ASC, its wrong

Comment: its not ordering by any of the fields, just giving a random order

Comment: Could you provide some sample data?

Comment: May I also suggest that you give the columns better names, like kills and deaths (guessing here, since it's a game).

Comment: ok im going to rename after everything works..
heres just a few fields from the result (cid and gid are unique and primary keys)
http://pastebin.com/d4b5867fe

Comment: `cid` isn't unique in the pastebin sample. 2 and 3 each repeat twice.

Comment: If you project onto the columns of `player` (`(cid,k,d)`), you end up with `(3,4,0)`, `(3,0,2)`, `(2,2,8)` and `(2,0,4)` in `table player (cid, k, d)`, hence `cid` isn't unique.

Comment: oh sorry it was a problem with my paste in the first column, its all ok about the query its just a order problem...i just found something, check the answer from Jason George its the negative values

Comment: You should edit the question and add the result of the query, the result you expect and (if you can put it into words) a description of the result you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`SELECT (player.k-player.d), player.cid, player.k, player.d, gg.gg_id, gg.name, gg.img, cc.cid, cc.name, cc.class, cc.gg_idFROM player LEFT JOIN cc ON cc.cid = player.cid LEFT JOIN gg ON gg.gg_id = cc.gg_id ORDER BY (player.k-player.d) DESC`

I did a quick query of my own and the results appear to be unordered (despite the fact the were) until I added the `SELECT (player.k-player.d)`.  MySQL also complained about ommiting the table name in the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: i get a #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)...if i put table(player.k-player.d),  player (k-d) or database(player k - player d) i get unkown colums errors

Comment: i did just for a try your simple "select player k - player d from xxx" and i noticed that some of the colums are giving me: 18446744073709551614...they both are INT and have legit values

Comment: yeah its definitely something about negative values..i ordered by k+d and it worked..so know what?

Comment: ok i changed the colums to FLOAT and know its working...why does mysql needs that, if im not inserting negative numbers there, just getting then in the query? they were INT(11) unsigned, now they are float unsigned

Comment: My guess is since the numbers are unsigned MySQL was performing the subtraction as an unsigned operation and the result for negative numbers was an overflow.  It's unclear, however, why float works.  If you'd like to maintain your column as INT(11) unsigned you can do (CAST(player.k AS SIGNED) - CAST(player.d AS SIGNED)).  You could potentailly still get an overflow here, however, if you exceed the maximum value for an unsigned int in either column.

Comment: hm thanks for your help, im going to make everything "FLOAT" since i only going to put numbers 0-999999 in the columns, i think theres no problem them